# ContentType.URLENC with sending API REQUEST

Tags: java, api, postman, rest-assured

I started API testing recently and facing different content-types each time, and i wan to know specific in what case we use ContentType.URLENC, I kinda sure we use it with **x-www-form-urlencoded**, but still confusing and we use it with usually POST request ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, when you want to send infomation to server, you need to tell the server how you structure your message in BODY part. Below is some basic ContentType:

- Using key-value with`&`: you can choose `x-www-form-urlencoded`.Since there are some special characters in your message, then these need to be encoded. That's why `urlencoded`.

Eg: name=abc&age=20

- Json type: choose `application/json` .

Eg:

```
{
    "name": "abc",
    "age": 20 
}
```

- Want to send a file: choose `form-data`

Secondly, BODY part usually goes with POST and PUT request.